# Pandas replace is executing over two separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to make a temporary dataframe where NaN values are replaced by zeros without affecting the original dataframe. However, I noticed that when I replace the NaN's of df_2 with 0s the corresponding column in df_1 is also changed. Have I done something wrong here when creating df_2?

Code

```
d = {'A':[np.nan, np.nan],'B':[1,2]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_2 = df_1
print(df_1)
print(df_2)
df_2['A'] = df_2['A'].replace(np.nan,0)
print(df_1)
print(df_2)
```

Outputs

```
    A  B
0 NaN  1
1 NaN  2
    A  B
0 NaN  1
1 NaN  2

     A  B
0  0.0  1
1  0.0  2
     A  B
0  0.0  1
1  0.0  2
```

Comment: `df_2 = df_1` - now you have two variables referencing the same dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use deep copy

```
df_2 = df_1.copy()
```

See more in [pandas.DataFrame.copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)